# Cross-subscription Azure SQL backup/export/sync without using SQL Logins

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

We want to have an automated scheduled snapshot of a Azure SQL database replicated from one Subscription to another, where the databases require Active Directory authentication and have SQL Logins disabled. I have looked at two options so far:

1. Use **New-AzSqlDatabaseExport** PowerShell cmdlet to export database
   .dacpac into storage account in the destination subscription, then
   use **New-AzSqlDatabaseImport** to import from storage account into
   target database.
2. Use Database Sync Groups to schedule daily replication between "hub"
   and "member" database.

Both of these options only appear to work with SQL Admin logins; I don't see a way to connect using a Service Principal or Managed Identity in either case.

Does anyone have a suggested best practice for setting this up (preferably from an Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline or Azure Function App) without having to re-enable SQL Logins to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add AAD logins for service principals with the `CREATE USER [unique-service-principal-name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#azure_active_directory_principal)). Then, depending on the level of access you want to give the service principal, you can `ALTER ROLE [appropriate_role] ADD MEMBER [unique-service-principal-name]`.

There's also a little more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview.

We have this setup and run `Invoke-SqlCmd` scripts from our CI. The newest version of the SqlServer module has the -AccessToken flag on the `Invoke-SqlCmd` command, so you can retrieve the token for the CI service principal and then pass it in instead of a username/password.

Comment: how do you run invoke-sqlcmd? i've tried doing it in an azure function and for some reason it cannot import the module. I have a perms scripts in a storage account and was trying to run the script from a function

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of doing it with an ARM template and running new-azgroupdeployment in an azure function to read the json and copy the DB across subscriptions. running it on a timer daily and now working on a way to run a script to restore permissions